# Parse Order of embeds that embed

Tags: templates, parse-order, embeds, template-scripting, template-partials

Assume the following:

1. Template A embeds Template B
2. Template B embeds Template C
3. Template C is a simple Channel entries loop that outputs a particular field value

In the above setup, nothing is outputted by Template C. However, if Template A embeds Template C directly, it works fine.

What's going on here? How do I make Template C work when embedded by Template B?

Comment: You might have to post some example code.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look at some of the proposed answers here and try to figure out how to strip down my code to show the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depth isn't an issue with embeds and neither is URLs, so if the embed works from template A, it will work from Template B.  So it isn't any parameter issue (unless you use embed variables in the parameters - see 2 below).

Three factors that are most likely:

1. The embed in Template B is within a conditional which is not being met.
2. You're passing embed variables from template A and incorrectly passing them to Template C from B.
3. There's a error in Template C which means it doesn't render (add-on?) - dump a test string outside any channel:entries tag pair to check if the template is accessed at all (this is also a good test for no. 2).

Seeing as we don't know your template code, I'm going to guess at no. 2 as being at fault (it's the one that usually catches me out the most).

Answer (score 0):

Can you just check by outputting anything out of channel entry tag and see if its working.

If its working check channel entry tag. Also check by using parameter dynamic="no" within channel entry tag.